# Ejecutar funcion al entrar en mi VUE COMPONENT

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Tengo una duda y es que si realmente el mounted() ejecuta las funciones que estan dentro de ellas automaticamente (es decir al entrar a la pàgina, yo creo que si)

```
 mounted() {
            this.listarRegistro(this.desde,this.hasta)
            this.controlRegistros();
        }
```

Mi duda viene porque yo en mi funcion de controlRegistros() recorro un **array de objetos** (este array se llena en la funcion de listar registros), y lo que hago es que si en encuentro algun objeto con su campo vacio me deshabilite un boton.

Mis otras dudas son... estoy recorriendo bien el array? estoy acciendo bien al atributo del objeto? (element.final)

Bueno hago todo eso y el boton que deberia deshabilitar sigue habilitado, entonces no se si realmente está ejecutando la funcion controlRegistros() al entrar a la pàgina o es que el array esta mal montado....

```
 controlRegistros(){
                var permitir=1;


                 for (let index = 0; index < this.arrayRegistro.length; index++) {
                     var element = this.arrayRegistro[index];
                      if(element.final==null || element.final==''){
                         permitir=0;
                     }
                 }

                 if(permitir==0){
                     var desactivar=document.getElementById("butRegistrar");
                     desactivar.disabled=true;
                 }
            }
```

Comment: El problema era que nunca recorria el array(porque estaba vacio) por eso nunca entraba al if y logicamente nunca cambiaba la variable 'permitir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno el problema que tenia es que el array que recorria estaba vacio, suponog que aun no entiendo bien el funcionamiento de Vue, bueno sabiendo esto he puesto el codigo de la funcion controlHorario() justo debajo de la función donde lleno el array y yaa funciona, gracias por tu respuesta igualmentee, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debemos hacer es refactorizar el método, haremos uso de la función `forEach` para recorrer el arreglo:

```
controlRegistros() {

 let permitir = true;
 let registros = this.arrayRegistro;

 registros.forEach(registro => {
    if(registro.final == null || registro.final == ''){
        permitir = false;
        break;
    }
 });

 return permitir;
}
```

Como habrá notado, no he incrustado el cambio del botón directamente. Lo que se debería hacer, a mi parecer, es *crear una propiedad* en el `data` del componente:

```
data() {
 // Otras propiedades
 permitir: true
}
```

Hagamos provecho de las potentes herramientas que posee VueJS. Para desabilitar el botón lo podremos hacer con la directiva **v-if** o con un **atributo dinámico**, lo realizaremos con un atributo dinámico → **:disabled**.

Lo único que debemos poner a nuestro *button*, será algo como:

```
<button :disabled="!permitir">Mi botón</button>
```

Y en nuestro `mounted()`:

```
mounted() {

this.permitir = controlRegistros();
}
```

Nótese que también la propiedad pudimos haberlo cambiado directamente en el método, pero no lo recomiendo, ya que posteriormente podrías necesitar realizar una acción con esa propiedad o utilizar el método. Además, ayuda también con la legibilidad del código para saber cómo se llegó a modificar su valor.

Comment: Deshabilita el boton pero no entiendo por que(supongo que como por defecto le doy al valor 'permitir=true" en el data y en el disabled del boton tengo disabled:!permitir entonces me desactiva el boton, pero a la ves tmb se queja que no encuentra la propiedad 'permitir' entonces no entiendo nadaa), porque me dice que no en encuentra ni la propiedad permitir y que la funcion controlRegistros() no esta definida entonces realmente nunca ha entrado al foreach.

Comment: Podría subir el componente completo o un enlace a ello para verlo y poder ayudarle?.

Comment: He publicado una respuesta, el problema es que el array que recorria estaba vacio, es decir nunca entraba al foreach.

Comment: Entiendo, que bueno que esté solucionado, saludos.